# I did the process to find the logical equivalence to the following formula but i’m not sure if it is right.

Tags: logic, solution-verification

(P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q)
(P ∧ Q) ∨ (¬Q ∧ P) (Commutative law)
P ∧ (Q ∨ ¬Q) ∧ P (Associative law)
P ∧ P (Tautology law)
P (Absorption law)

............

(P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q)
P ∧ (Q ∨ ¬Q)[Distributive law]
P [Tautology law]

Comment: Your application of the associative law is not correct, as you can only associate over the same operator. Instead, you should use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic).

Comment: The associative law only works on expressions that involve a single logical operator, canonically $X\land (Y \land Z) = (X \land Y) \land Z$. Instead the distributive laws (or, more precisely, their logical counterparts) should be used.

Comment: I wrote under my first answer what I think is the correct answer. Could you please tell me if II applied the distributive law correctly?

Comment: Yes, your correction is correct.